# Arduino with navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, uav, obstacle-avoidance, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to launch the robot_configuration.launch file with arduino for the Navigation Stack usage? If yes, how? Rosserial_arduino?

My arduino is used for all the UAV controls. I am unsure of what to add in the robot_configuration launch file. From my senior's report, they mentioned that there's no odom for UAV but navigation stack requires it for the local_planner. So, I hope to gather some guidance from here as I am quite confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65656/arduino-with-navigation-stack/) by [Edward Ramsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/4814/edward-ramsay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-06-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you got the spirit. By now the best way to use the navigation stack (which need lot of computacional resources) is by runing it on a computer and just passing command to the robot_base (which is commanded by the arduino).

So you should run rosserial on the arduino and make it subscribe the cmd_vel messages, also if you have wheel encoders or
other type of sensor you could plug it on arduino and publish its info to ros.

You should check http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) with karma: 68 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1